# How to optimize a query - extracting count info using a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I structure the below query to run through multiple databases all at the same time.

To calculate the total number of active users in the db, I currently have to run the query one database at a time.

Is there some kind of foreach function I can run dynamically?

```
with data as
(select p.CoNum CoNum, p.LastName, p.Name,co.name Company, liGender.Description as Gender, liEth.Description as EthnicGroup,Isnull(Limed.Description,'Not Specified') FinancialAid,
  vwPTU.[UserP Type] as UserPType

from UsersP p
  left outer join ListItem liGender on liGender.Id = p.Gender
  left outer join ListItem liEth on liEth.Id = p.EthnicGroup
  left outer join ListItem limed on limed.Id = p.FinancialAidId
  inner join UserPOrgNodeAssociation pona on P.Id = pona.UserPId
  inner join CoAssociation coda on pona.CoNodeDescAssociationId = coda.Id
  inner join Company co on coda.companyid=co.id
  left outer join [dbo].[vw_XUserUniqueView] vwPTU on p.Id = vwPTU.Id
    and vwPTU.[ValidToDate] > '2015/12/31 23:59 PM'

where vwPTU.[User Type] is not null

)
select Company, count(distinct CoNum) as Total
from data
group by company
```

Comment: The with clause is just for illustration, right? It is really a view you are selecting from instead, correct? If not, then you could simplify your with clause significantly by removing unnecessary parts.

Comment: Yes the with clause was for illustration. True though, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SP_MSForEachDB procedure..

```
exec sp_msforeachdb  'Your Query here'
```